# How to update node count on Service Fabric cluster?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to update the node count of my Service Fabric Cluster. I use PowerShell to deploy the Template below with the following command:
`New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -name "ExampleDeployment3" -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -TemplateFile "template.json"`.

When I run `Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` I get a list of all previous tries of deployments. Only the latest one `ExampleDeployment3` is "Running"

```
{
  "$schema":"http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json",
  "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
  "parameters":{
    "existingVMSSName":{
      "type":"string",
      "metadata":{
        "description":"Name of existing VM Scale Set"
      }
    },
    "newCapacity":{
      "type":"int",
      "metadata":{
        "description":"Number of desired VM instances"
      }
    },
    "vmSku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_A1",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Size of VMs in the VM Scale Set."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources":[
    {
      "type":"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets",
      "apiVersion":"2016-03-30",
      "name":"[parameters('existingVMSSName')]",
      "location":"[resourceGroup().location]",
      "sku":{
        "name":"[parameters('vmSku')]",
        "tier":"Standard",
        "capacity":"[parameters('newCapacity')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I do, the Deployment runs, and runs, and runs, and runs. In the Azure Portal I can see that 2 new instances are "Creating..." and 4 out of 5 default ones are "Updating...". 6/7 nodes got the "VM stopped" status. The only one that is running is the first Node.

However, it never seems to complete. I've clicked "Start" on one of the "VM Stopped" nodes but it does not seem to work. It is still stuck in "Updating" or "Creating".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with doing this through powershell, so I can't help there, but in the past I've always achieved this though [azure resource explorer](https://resources.azure.com/). You can find your nodes by going to subscription->resource groups->{{resource group name}}->compute->vm scale sets. You can click read/write on the top right to enable editing the arm templates right there. From there it's as simple as upping the instance count on your vmss and saving.